# Sharepoint audit reports automation with power bi

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, powerbi, audit-log-reports

I was wondering if this possible. To automate the SharePoint Online Audit log report i.e a user viewing a page of the site from the excel spreadsheet and using powershell (im assuming) to create a power bi report?

This power bi will show who such things as most active users , most view documents per month.

How is this achievable? Has this be done before if so could you explain how it 
has been done?

We currently do this process manually. i.e download the report from excel and update the coloumns for powerbi and update the format.

Ideally we are using office 365 groups and we would want to the see in the report how many users are in those 0365 groups. But with being restricted to connecting to azure, and exchange to the connection in power bi this can't be achieved. Hence I was looking for another way to process the audit reports

Thanks!